# Wiimote Working on Samsung Galaxy S II Without Root

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, bluetooth, game-controllers, bluetooth-pairing

I've been reading everywhere that the Wiimote doesn't work with Samsung Galaxy S II because of the bluetooth stack on the device which is not able to pair with the Wiimote.

Many claim that it's possible to get it to work by installing a rom like MIUI which has the stock bluetooth drivers but I'm not up to rooting just yet.

Is it possible to get the gamepad to hook with the phone without having to root it and get a custom rom?

Comment: Doesn't your first paragraph answer the question?

Comment: If you read up on the subject you will see why it doesn't answer my question. In my first paragraph I explained to those who are not aware that the Bluetooth stack presented with the Galaxy S II doesn't accept Wiimote when pairing. Possible solutions would be to change the stack or using some application to achieve compatibility. Since after googling for it I didn't find any answer, as this is a recent matter, I decided to ask the question. Where am I wrong here?

Comment: Hmm OK, I suppose it might be possible to get an app to manage the connection.  You certainly can't change the stack without root, though.

Comment: I see, so changing drivers in official roms isn't supported in the current version of Android for smartphones at all? Sorry if my questions are easy or something but I'm new to Android.

Comment: Yes, that's right, though with the SGS II I believe you can flash kernels and modems without root (but that will void your warranty just as rooting or a custom ROM would).  No worries, they're fine :)

Comment: That is precisely why I'm not going to root my phone as of yet. I paid an insurance for it in case someone steals it or if it breaks by accident and I don't want to lose that or the warranty if anything goes wrong by accident. It would be money wasted :/